# How to get specific value from a xml string in c#

Tags: c#, xml, string, xelement

I have following string

```
<SessionInfo>
  <SessionID>MSCB2B-UKT3517_f2823910df-5eff81-528aff-11e6f-0d2ed2408332</SessionID>
  <Profile>A</Profile>
  <Language>ENG</Language>
  <Version>1</Version>
</SessionInfo>
```

now I want to get the **value** of **SessionID**. I tried with below ..

```
var rootElement = XElement.Parse(output);//output means above string and this step has values
```

but in here,,

```
var one = rootElement.Elements("SessionInfo");
```

it didn't work.what can I do that.

and What if the xml string like below.can we use same to get the **sessionID**

```
<DtsAgencyLoginResponse xmlns="DTS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="DTS file:///R:/xsd/DtsAgencyLoginMessage_01.xsd">
  <SessionInfo>
    <SessionID>MSCB2B-UKT351ff7_f282391ff0-5e81-524548a-11eff6-0d321121e16a</SessionID>
    <Profile>A</Profile>
    <Language>ENG</Language>
    <Version>1</Version>
  </SessionInfo>
  <AdvisoryInfo />
</DtsAgencyLoginResponse>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rootElement` already references `<SessionInfo>` element. Try this way :

```
var rootElement = XElement.Parse(output);
var sessionId = rootElement.Element("SessionID").Value;
```

Comment: @bill I agree with HimBromBeere. Anyway, the keyword is *default namespace*. The 2nd XML has default namespace `xmlns="DTS"`. Try to search for how to select element in namespace using LINQ-to-XML...

Answer (score 2):

You can select node by xpath and then get value:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<SessionInfo>
                 <SessionID>MSCB2B-UKT3517_f2823910df-5eff81-528aff-11e6f-0d2ed2408332</SessionID>
                 <Profile>A</Profile>
                 <Language>ENG</Language>
                  <Version>1</Version>
              </SessionInfo>");

string xpath = "SessionInfo/SessionID";    
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

var value = node.InnerText;
```

Comment: The call to `String.Format` is completely unnecessary here

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
   private string parseResponseByXML(string xml)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/SessionInfo");
        string node ="";
        if (xnList != null && xnList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                node= xn["SessionID"].InnerText;

            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```

Your nodes :

`xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/SessionInfo");`

Different sample

```
 xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/SessionInfo/node/node");
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not do this manually. This is horrible. Use .NET built in stuff to make it simpler and more reliable

[XML Serialisation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)

This is the right way to do it. You create Classes and let them be serialized automatically from an XML string.

Comment: The `XElement` IS ".NET-Stuff" and comes with LinqToXml. It´s absoutely okay to do it like this.

Comment: I guess OP is only interested in a single value, thus he won´t need this overhead of creating the classes and adding the serializer-attributes. The approach of har07 works smart and is absouteley fine for this purpose.